# RewriteRule error in the htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem which is as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^site   site.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^site/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ site.php?parameter=1$ [NC,L]
```

The idea is to recognize that if there is a parameter in the url.
So that's what I want:

```
www.example.com/site
www.example.com/site/1
```

According to my knowledge, but I simply was trying things didn't work out.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pair of rules the first one will match *both* example URLs. So the second rule will *never* get applied. You have to change the order of the rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?site/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ site.php?parameter=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/?site/?$ site.php [NC,L]
```

Note that I also modified the now second rule slightly to prevent it matching paths like `/sitelist` for example. Also it prevents a redirection loop because of matching `/site.php` too... The initial `/?` I also added allows to use the same rules in the http servers host configuration without modification, not only in `.htaccess` style dynamic configuration files.

A general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files ("`.htaccess`"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Good answer Arkascha. +1

Comment: Aah, i got it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This line will redirect any URL that begins with `site` to site.php:

```
RewriteRule ^site   site.php [NC,L]
```

This line will never run because `site` was already caught and redirected by the first rule:

```
RewriteRule ^site/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ site.php?parameter=$1 [NC,L]
```

So simply running the second rule first will resolve the issue as it will trigger the more specific case.

Comment: what is the **=1$** for?

Comment: I copied and pasted the original without noticing this bug.  Fixed.